# WCF 403 Errors

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, iis

I'm getting different errors with a WCF service.  This service has worked fine in all of our test environments so far, until now.  We normally having it running under IIS 6 on Windows Server 2003. I had it running under a Windows XP Pro VM that was connected to our company's domain.  Our IT guy removed the VM from the company domain just recently.

Now I'm getting errors like these:

> An existing connection was forcibly
>   closed by the remote host.
>
> The remote server returned an error:
>   (403) Forbidden.
>
> The HTTP request was forbidden with
>   client authentication scheme
>   'Anonymous'.

IIS is configured to allow Anonymous access.  The IIS user also has permission to view/execute in the service folder.

The service works fine for some calls but not for others.  The application calls the service when loading, but then later on in a separate call it does this.

The service is using wsHttpBinding:

```
 <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="wsHttpBindingSettings" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
        <message establishSecurityContext="false" />
      </security>
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
```

Comment: I took out my one area where I was doing threading to access something in the service.  It still doesn't answer the question, but at least my code is working right now.  I don't understand why the code works fine with the service running locally and on our Windows Server 2003 box, but not in our XP Pro VM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the key to this issue was that it was running in IIS 5 on Windows XP.  IIS 5 in XP has a maximum number of connections of 10.  Once we exceeded that limit I believe we received 403 errors.  We fixed this issue by using a Server 2008 VM instead of XP for doing demos on a laptop.

Answer (score 0):

*The service works fine for some calls but not for others. The application calls the service when loading, but then later on in a separate call it does this.*

Maybe the calls that worked did not perform any sensitive operations, like accessing DB's or files? Under what permission does the IIS application pool run, does it use client impersonation? That would explain the issue..

Also you might want to try this setting:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="xyz">
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True"/>
```

Comment: Pretty much every call does sensitive operations.  I don't think any of those are causing problems.  I already have includingExceptionDetailsInFaults enabled and I don't get anymore details.

I'm not sure about the IIS application pool though.

Answer (score 0):

same problem here, i've mitigated the problem by adding a default binding to the endpoint and explicitly setting the security level to "None" where possible, now it works better but if calls are made too frequently to the server it fails again, i've also noticed that the development webserver in VS2008 nnever fails even with very high frequency call.
so it should be related to IIS in some way and i suspect that is something related to the duration of the security context but these are only my guess so far, i've not found a real solution

Comment: problems appears only with the IIS version on XP, next IIS version (on Windows server 2003 for example) works great in any condition

Answer (score 0):

It may be caused by a combination of security settings in IIS and web.config.

If the settings in IIS were integrated and anonymous, and the settings in web.config were set to windows, with impersonate = false.

Then, when the machine was in the domain, integrated authentication would be used, and everything would work OK.

When the machine was removed from the domain, anonymous authenticaion would be used, then it would be the IIS anonymous user that is used to access the resources. This user has limited rights and therefore some calls can fail.

You could change the setting in web.config to impersonate = false, this would mean that the identity of the application pool would be used to access resources.